# whats the quickest way to get row count of innodb tables, in mysql 4.0?

Tags: mysql, innodb

MySQL 4.0 doesn't have information_schema and 'show table status from **db**' only gives approximate row count for innodb tables.

So whats the quickest way to get the count of innodb tables, of course other than count(*), which could be slower with big tables.

Comment: Two questions: Why are you using MySQL 4.0? It's ancient and unsupported. Why do you need an exact count of the entire table?

Comment: it turns out, both of your questions are related: Im actually upgrading from 4.0 to 5.0 and, call me paranoid or something, but i wanted to make sure that the upgrade was successful and so wanted to do a row count comparison of each table, before and after upgrade.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Updated**

When using InnoDB the *only* accurate count of rows in your entire table is COUNT(*). Since your upgrade from 4.0 to 5.0 will only occur once, you'll just have to deal with the speed.

Comment: Thanks hobodave. As I just responded to your comment above, i would like to do a sanity check before and after migration and so i can't go for a separate table approach, in this case.

Answer (score 1):

This applies to all versions of MySQL.  As other commenters have pointed out - there is no fast SELECT COUNT(*) in InnoDB.  Part of the reason for this is that InnoDB is multi-versional, and it will depend on the context of your transaction how many rows there are supposed to be in a table.

There are some workarounds:

1) If you never delete, SELECT MAX(id) should return the right number of rows.

2) Instead of deleting rows, you can archive them to a 'deleted rows table' (a lot of people seem to want to keep everything these days).  Assuming that the delete is a much smaller subset of still current, you may be able to subtract count(*) from deleted_rows from SELECT max(id) from not_deleted.

3) Use triggers.  This sucks for performance.

There's quite a technical discussion on this problem here:
http://mysqlha.blogspot.com/2009/08/fast-count-for-innodb.html

Answer (score 1):

Wait! There is a fast way! Use a trigger and a meta table..

```
CREATE TABLE meta (
`name` char(32) NOT NULL ,
`value_int` int ,
unique (name)
) ENGINE = INNODB;
insert into meta (name, value_int) values ('mytable.count', 0);
```

then

```
set delimiter |

CREATE TRIGGER mytablecountinsert AFTER INSERT ON mytable
    FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
        update meta set value_int=value_int+1 where name='mytable.count';
    END;
|

CREATE TRIGGER mytablecountdelete AFTER DELETE ON mytable
    FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
        update meta set value_int=value_int-1 where name='mytable.count';
    END;
|
```

Comment: This approach puts a burden on the insert / delete moments. For the large tables there is also probably a large number of inserts / deletes. I would not recommend this then.

Answer (score -2):

Well, using `*` is definitely not optimal but how about just 1 column.  I usually use the `id` column to count # of rows.

Comment: in MySQL, a specific column is not needed as one can just do: select count(1) from my_table

Comment: Thanks Knix and Caughlan. Since my innodb tables are huge, the count(1) also takes a lot of time. I wonder if dropping all the indices on innodb tables would expedite the count(1).

Comment: Then I think it would be best just to keep a counter in a different table whenever a row gets inserted or deleted.  Is this an option for you?

Comment: It would've been an option if i'm designing the DB now but the tables are there for years now and i need this count() for a sanity check for my 4.0 to 5.0 mysql upgrade.